# Ignore property when syncing

Tags: ensembles

I would like to store `PHAsset.localIdentifier` in my database. Syncing this does not make sense since each device will have different identifier for given photo. Can I somehow configure Ensambles to ignore one property when syncing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add CDEIgnoredKey to the property in the user info of the model, with a value 1, and Ensembles will not sync the property.